# Creating a new file from a cpp program in Ubuntu

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, filesystems

How do I create a new file from a cpp program in Ubuntu, and is it any different from windows.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We're willing to help you. Please take the time to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read up on [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55124434/edit) the question accordingly. Please create [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and give sample inputs, outputs and the error messages you get, if any. This will help us to determine what is going on and improve your chances to get an answer.

Comment: ***is it any different from windows*** Not really outside of the path.

Comment: "is it and different from windows"—have you *tried*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare a stream class file and open that text file in writing mode. If the file is not present then it creates a new text file. Then check if the file does not exist or not created then return false otherwise return true.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

// Driver code
int main()
{
    const char *path = "/home/user/Gfg.txt";

    // fstream is Stream class to both
    // read and write from/to files.
    // file is object of fstream class
    fstream file(path);

    // opening file "Gfg.txt"
    // in out(write) mode
    // ios::out Open for output operations.
    file.open(path, ios::out);

    // If no file is created, then
    // show the error message.
    if (!file)
    {
        cout << "Error in creating file!!!" << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    cout << "File created successfully." << endl;

    // closing the file.
    // The reason you need to call close()
    // at the end of the loop is that trying
    // to open a new file without closing the
    // first file will fail.
    file.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Source [geeksforgeeks : C++ program to create a file](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-program-to-create-a-file/)

Comment: Where does the file open? Can I control it?

Comment: Read the comments on the code, each line is pre-commented so you understand the procedure.

Comment: I read the comments, but did not see anything about path, if for example I want to create a file in a specific path, can I do it?

Comment: Yes, you can do that. I updated the code so it creates a file in a specific path.

Comment: @ProgrammerIrving Change the path according to the system you are using. And upvote the answer pls.

Answer (score -1):

if you are using linux with gcc/g++ command line compile tool, 
compile the program with:

```
g++ your_program.cpp -o your_program
```

you can add execute permission to the file with the command:

```
sudo chmod a+x your_program
```

and then double click it, it will execute

OR:
You could use an IDE like Code::Blocks / CLion

Comment: Hi, probably misunderstood me, fixed the title. I meant how to make the cpp program create a new file on the computer. Sorry.